# quill-emoji : Emoji is not being rendered

Tags: javascript, angular, quill

I'm trying to implement quill-emoji with ngx-quill. However, I'm not able to see the emoji's in the pop-up or when an emoji is inserted. I'm guessing that I'm missing a CSS inclusion (I cannot see this being mentioned in [github](https://github.com/contentco/quill-emoji)).

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-quill-emoji?file=src/app/app.component.ts) of the implementation.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the styles in angular.json styles array :

```
"src/styles.css",
              "./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.core.css",
              "./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.bubble.css",
              "./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css",
              "./node_modules/quill-emoji/dist/quill-emoji.css",
              "./node_modules/quill-mention/dist/quill.mention.min.css"
```

I found this on ngx-quill examples project.